# How can I debug code that has very large symbol tables?

Tags: linux, c++, debugging

I have a binary that has very large symbol tables due to extensive meta-programming, so the types are very large.

I can't load this program into `gdb` or `cgdb` because it will either segfault or simply take several minutes/hours to lookup a value.

Is there an alternative to `gdb` that will work with very large types? I can't use windows.

Comment: If your code is "seg fault"ing gdb then that is probably your single biggest bug all by itself. Split your code into one or more .so files and a small executable, possibly adding a test build for each class. Or consider spitting the tasks to be performed into several programs in a pipe.

Comment: @SteveBarnes that would be wonderful! But alas, it's not an option for various reasons.

Comment: If you are running on a 32 bit OS, why can't you switch to a 64 bit OS?  Then "too big" would have be "rediculously too big".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the size of the code that has been developed with GDB the most likely problem is trying to work with too little RAM:

1. Add more RAM to your system - **real** RAM **not** Virtual or
2. if that is impossible on the target machine then run your code to be debugged on the target system with gdbserver and remote debug from another.